# Apache module creation tutorial contains code with errors. How to fix?

Tags: c, apache, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I went to the following URL for instructions on building an apache module:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

It states halfway down the page that code similar to the following is required for a custom module to process entries in the apache configuration file:

```
static const command_rec example_directives[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("exampleEnabled", example_set_enabled, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "Enable or disable mod_example"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("examplePath", example_set_path, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "The path to whatever"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE2("exampleAction", example_set_action, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "Special action value!"),
    { NULL }
};
```

It compiles fine under apxs using no gcc options. it doesn't compile with extended error checking on. For example, I issued this command:

```
apxs -i -a -Wc,Werror -Wc,-Wall -Wc,-Wextra -Wc,-O2 -c ./sample.c --enable-debug=YES
```

That attempts to execute `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 sample.c` and the errors I receive are:

```
./sample.c:178: warning: missing initializer
./sample.c:178: warning: (near initialization for 'example_directives[4].func')
```

The line of the error points to the line that only contains `{ NULL }`.

The apache module tutorial also suggests we use functions with parameters programmers will rarely use.  As a result, I've been receiving these warnings:

```
warning: unused parameter
```

How do I fix all these errors with extended error checking enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc wants you to initialize all members of the structure apparently. Try replacing the last entry with { NULL, { NULL }, NULL, 0, 0, NULL }. The values should match command_rec structure definition typically found in /usr/include/httpd/http_config.h

Comment: Now my error from trying that is `./sample.c:178: warning: missing braces around initializer
./sample.c:178: warning: (near initialization for 'example_directives[4].func')`

Comment: Ah, I see. cmd_func is a union, not a plain pointer. The second field should be { NULL }.